# Why is the first git push rejected due to conflict, but choosing to push again succeeds?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, push

Here is the scenario:
1.  I make some local changes
2.  I do a Git --> Commit then Commit and Push
3.  I encounter a 'rejected' message due to conflicts
4.  I merge and resolve the conflict, deciding to keep my local changes
5.  I commit and push again, and again see a message that it is rejected
6.  Unfazed, I do another Push, and it succeeds!

Can someone tell me why the second push attempt decides to succeed?

Comment: How strange :s, perhaps it has something to do with `git` integrals. As long as you successfully pushed and you don't experience any issues at this point. I'd suggest to just leave it lol

Comment: Not enough information to answer. Does this happen to you a lot? I've been using Git for almost a decade and I've never seen it.

Comment: There has to be something between steps 3 and 4 - most likely a `git pull` - after which you would get to solve possible conflicts.

Comment: No extra steps between 3 & 4.  At least nothing visible to us.  We're able to reproduce it 100% of the time.  At this point, it's just a small annoyance and I am sort of willing to just do what e.doroskevic says and just leave it.  :)  It's possible we have some other settings that need attention, but three of us just installed and set up IntelliJ and all of us see this happening.  Weird!

Comment: What are you pushing to?

Comment: Regarding what happened between steps 3 and 4: Maybe you have the option [Auto-update if push of the current branch was rejected](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/mps/3.3/git.html#autoUpdate) enabled in your IntelliJ config? In that case IntelliJ will automatically do a pull if the push is rejected. However this would not explain why the push fails in step 5 and succeeds in step 6.

Comment: Could you post the message from IntelliJs Event Log which was issued in step 5? Maybe it does explain why this push failed.

Comment: I think there was a Pull indeed happening behind the scenes as 1615903 suggests.  We weren't merging conflicts the way we should have been doing, it looks like.  We've changed our process a little to handle these appropriately.  Sorry, we're new to Git and sort of still learning how to use it.  Thanks for all of the comments.